# Oracle Discoverer - Multiple Join On Single Table

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence

I have two folders defined under business area from database tables called `EMP` and `PROJECTS`

`EMP` table has the following columns

```
emp_number
emp_name
```

`projects` table has the following columns

```
proj_id
proj_initiated_by
proj_started_by
proj_closed_by
```

Joins are generated as

```
emp.emp_number -> projects.proj_initiated_by (one_to_many)
emp.emp_number -> projects.proj_started_by (one_to_many)
emp.emp_number -> projects.proj_closed_by (one_to_many)
```

In Discoverer Desktop, when I'm trying to create a report, I'm able to see
employee name of person who initiated (initiated_by)

However for started_by and closed_by, I am not sure how to display employee name of person who started and closed project.

```
employee name of person who started (started_by)    
employee name of person who started (closed_by)
```

Appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve the below

```
emp.emp_number -> projects.proj_initiated_by (one_to_many)
emp.emp_number -> projects.proj_started_by (one_to_many)
emp.emp_number -> projects.proj_closed_by (one_to_many)
```

is to create three objects of emp table and create join for

```
projects.proj_initiated_by = emp1.emp_number 
projects.proj_started_by = emp2.emp_number 
projects.proj_closed_by = emp3.emp_number
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it in 2 variants:

join emp to every person - so 3 joins 

make some function or (select emp_name from emp where emp_number = ...) inside selective part

Comment: I do have three joins in business area, however in Discoverer Desktop, not sure how to use three joins to achieve desired result. Using select query is an option as I am looking to achieve it without SQL Query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the *particular* reporting tool that you might be using, but I can say that it is certainly okay to write an SQL query (or, to have the reporting-engine write one for you ...) which contains multiple references to the same table (e.g. `EMP`).

```
  SELECT i.emp_name AS initiated_by_name, 
         s.emp_name AS started_by_name,
         p.project_d
  FROM projects p
    INNER JOIN emp i ON (i.emp_number = p.proj_initiated_by)
    INNER JOIN emp s ON (s.emp_number = p.proj_started_by)
```

Notice how I have used aliases (`i`, `s`, `p`) to "disambiguate" the two different, and unrelated, references to the table `emp`.  (And to the `projects` table to which both are `JOINed`.)  I have also used `AS` to give distinct column-names to the results.

**Also:** I chose to use an `INNER JOIN` here, instead of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.  So, this query will only return projects which have both an initiator and a starter.  That was an arbitrary choice, and perhaps an inappropriate one.  Had I elected to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, every project would be listed but `initiated_by_name` and/or `started_by_name` might be `NULL`, and the result-set would be bigger.

If this reporting-tool is doing the work of creating the SQL queries for you, you will find (perhaps after a little digging into the *"advanced"* section of the user-manual) that it *will* have some means of creating queries like this one. (Including the various types of `JOINs`.)

Comment: Mike, in Discoverer there is an option to use SQL queries to generate reports and one could use database objects to create business area in order to create a report. I am aware of using SQL query to achieve the desired result. But wondering how to do this using folders based on database objects.

Comment: Here I have to say, "I haven't used Discoverer myself [yet], so I don't know."  This *might* be a situation that "breaks the metaphor" of 'folders,' unless there's an obvious way to include a 'folder' *(nee:* "a database table") more than once in your report-definition.  So, you *might* have stumbled into a case where you're just going to have to write an SQL query.  Or, there might be some "advanced" feature.  I can only meaningfully describe "what actually has to be presented to the SQL server," not the gyrations that must be employed in this-or-that product in order to get there. Good luck.

Comment: P.S.:  You can be *sure* that the designer(s) of this reporting product *knew* about this sort of requirement, and that they therefore will have made some sort of allowance for it ... hopefully, without simply "throwing-in the towel and forcing you to write SQL."  In Microsoft Access (and Paradox), for example, there's the concept of a "data model."  The requirement that you're dealing with is "'advanced,' yes, but really only *slightly* so ..."  Prowl through the middle-to-later sections of the manual.  :-)

Comment: Mike, I have managed to achieve without SQL, see the answer I have posted. Thanks for  your help though.

Comment: Ahh, good.  And what the reporting tool undoubtedly is *doing,* just behind the scenes, is to generate the necessary SQL, and joins.  *Perfecto!*  (It's often the case that you find yourself thinking:  "I know what I want this tool to [tell the SQL server to ...] do. Now, how do I tell this tool to do it?")